# Play! always load the initial-data

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x

My Bootstrap.java is:

```
@OnApplicationStart
public class Bootstrap extends Job {

    public void doJob() {
        // Check if the database is empty
        System.out.println("========================================================" + User.count());
        if(User.count() == 0) {
            Fixtures.loadModels("initial-data.yml");
        }
        System.out.println("========================================================" + User.count());
    }
}
```

Every time I restart the application, the database will be cleaned, then the `User.count()` is 0, so it reload the initial-data, and all my changes of the `User` lost. Can anybody help me? Thanks.

**Edit**:

In the application.conf I've set my database like this:

```
%server01.application.mode=PROD
%server01.db=mysql:root:secret@dbname
%server01.jpa.ddl=create
%server01.XForwardedSupport=127.0.0.1
```

Comment: how are you starting your app from the command line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your conf, try setting the ddl generation to `update` (or `validate`) instead of `create`:

```
%server01.jpa.ddl=update
```

Take a look at [this doc](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.1.1/guide11).

Comment: Thanks. You've got the point! Maybe I should use jpa.dll=none in the prod environment?

Comment: I would use the `validate` in prod, in order to check that my object model is consistent with the relationnal model.

Answer (score 0):

The database is probably set in memory. Please check application.conf and use a persistent database.

If I recall you only have to uncomment a few lines.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I'm using a persistent database and run my app in prod mode.